# while loop won't print the vowels properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Question is:

> ```
> longWord = 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious'
> ```
>
> Using a for loop, print the total number of vowels found in longWord (DO NOT use the count function!)

My code is:

```
vowel = 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u'    


for i in range(len(longWord)):
    if vowel in longWord[i]:
        print("Vowel at:", longword[i])
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: What do you get when you add `print(vowel)` in the second line?

Comment: When I do print(vowel), it prints 'a'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of

```
vowel = 'a' or 'e' or 'i' or 'o' or 'u'
```

will simply evaluate down to `vowel = 'a'`. That causes your issue.

Instead, you're looking for something like this:

```py
for i in range(len(longWord)):
    if longWord[i] in "aeiou":
        print("Vowel at:", longword[i])
```

This `in` operator checks whether the string `longWord[i]` is a substring of `"aeiou"`.

Alternatively, in Python you can perform what in other languages would be referred to as a for-each loop:

```py
for char in longWord:
    if char in "aeiou":
        print("Vowel at:", char)
```

This simplifies your code somewhat.